# Making/Building a kernel module inside a docker container

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I currently have my host system running Mac OS with docker. I have my Mac OS host system spawning a docker container.

The spawned docker container is currently running `ubuntu:19.10`

I am trying to build a kernel module inside the docker container

When I run

```
$> make
```

I get...

```
Building coolMod driver...
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/foo/coolMod modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.19.76-linuxkit/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:43: coolMod.ko] Error 2
```

The docker container does not have the kernel headers.

When I try to run:

```
$> apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.76-linuxkit
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.19.76-linuxkit'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.19.76-linuxkit'
```

How can I install kernel headers so I can build a kernel module from within my Docker container?

Thank you!

Comment: A kernel module is pretty specific to the kernel it's built for, and usually a container can't load or unload modules.  Where are you hoping to run the module?  Do you know the exact kernel version it will have?

Comment: Basically i'm trying to use a module called https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback ... It creates a virtual video device. However, I keep running into the issue of actually being able to load the module inside the container to make the driver available.

Comment: Docker containers can't load kernel modules.  You need a virtual machine with an isolated kernel for that.

Comment: Yep, that is also what i have concluded. I am in the process now of setting up a vm. thx

Comment: @DavidMaze do you have a source / further reading on that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to late, but in order to build a kernel module inside the container you should execute the container in --priviliged mode.

Apart from the dependencies kernel-devel and kernel-headers, the kernel should be built for your specific kernel version, so you should create a volume to link host:/lib/modules to your_container:/lib/modules.

A good starting point should be https://projectatomic.io/blog/2018/06/building-kernel-modules-with-podman/.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers don't have a kernel of their own; they use the kernel of the Docker host. So when you run `uname` command, the result you are seeing is that of the underlying Docker host. You can verify this by comparing the result of `uname -a` on the Docker host to the result in the Docker container.

This most probably the reason why your `make` as well as the `apt install` both are failing.

I'm not sure about the specific module you are trying to build and if it has any other dependencies. In general, you can build a kernel module in the Docker container if you have the kernel source in your Docker container. Try using a specific version of the kernel in your `apt install` command instead of using/relying on `uname` command. Then `$ make -C <path_to_kernel_src> M=$PWD`

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760612/319542) answer I just posted on another question.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, you'll need to add the repo for your OS which provides the kernel development resources.

For me, (on ubi8) I first needed to add the Oracle Linux 8 repository and its GPG key:

```
RUN rpm --import "https://yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-ol8"
RUN dnf config-manager --add-repo http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64
```

Then, you can install the development tools and modules:

```
RUN dnf install kernel-devel-$(uname -r) kernel-modules-$(uname -r) elfutils-libelf-devel -y
```

Note that this assumes the host is running the same kernel as you are developing a kernel module for.