# Load kernel module from mac os sierra host to a docker container

Tags: docker, kernel, containers, kernel-module

I've juste installed [a custom kernel module](https://github.com/sctplab/SCTP_NKE_ElCapitan) to enable SCTP support on my Macbook

And I would like to load this kernel module inside my docker container.

I tried to start a container using the *--cap-add SYS_MODULE* flag and install the *libsctp-dev lksctp-tools kmod* packages in the container to enable sctp using "modprobe sctp"... but unsuccessfully:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/modules.dep.bin' modprobe:
  FATAL: Module SCTP not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.13-moby
```

On a linux host, some people advise do to do like that : [Docker loading kernel modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013539/docker-loading-kernel-modules/37160346#37160346) but it's both uncompatible with macOS and "dirty"...

So my question is : Does anyone know how to use kernel module in a docker container using a macOs host ? Is that even possible ?

Comment: Your Mac is using a Darwin kernel, and Docker is using a Linux kernel. Not at all compatible. You might be able to do something like this, but you would have to go into the Linux VM that hosts Docker on your Mac and do it there. That is where the container kernels run - in Linux, not in macOS.

Comment: You can access the Linux VM like this BTW: `docker run --rm -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh`

Comment: @DanLowe post that as an answer, not a set of comments

Comment: @DerickBailey I intentionally didn't post it as an answer because it doesn't really answer the question "how can I add this kernel module to a container" - I don't know if you _can_ do that, much less _how_ to do it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that docker for mac runs over an hyperkit VM with alpine to get the linux kernel.

As mentionned by @DanLowe in the comments, we can access this VM using the following command : `docker run --rm -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh`

The kernel sources used by this VM are available here : https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit

I edited the *kernel/kernel_config* file and set **CONFIG_IP_SCTP=y** to enable SCTP support in the kernel.

Then I recompiled the kernel and copied my newly compiled kernel file (bzImage) to the docker for mac */Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/moby/vmlinuz64* kernel file.

Restarted docker for mac and...

`host>docker run -it debian
container>cat /proc/net/protocols 
protocol  size sockets  memory press maxhdr  slab module     cl co di ac io in de sh ss gs se re sp bi br ha uh gp em
SCTPv6    1416      1       0   no       0   yes  kernel      y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  y
SCTP      1256      0       0   no       0   yes  kernel      y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  y`

Pull Request [here](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/pull/1675).

Comment: not works for newer Docker for OSX because it keeps all linux files including kernel in `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/linuxkit/docker-for-mac.iso`